# Firebase Registration Token for Website

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am looking to integrate Firebase into an existing project.  I would like to create an administrative Website that would have the ability to create topics, and then post messages to topics.

From the mobile devices, the end user would be able to view the Topics that were created, and subscribe to them.

Ideally the administrative user would log into my website, opt to create a new Topic, and then from the backend I would send an HTTP request to FCM to create that topic.

The issue I am having is figuring out how to create Topics.  My understanding is that I need to pass in a Token in order to create topics, but I can't find where to create Tokens for a web user in their SDK.  Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score -1):

Topics in FCM follow a pub-sub model. There is no such explicit activity as creating a topic. You just **subscribe** to a topic. Usually you would subscribe from the client side using Android or iOS FCM APIs to subscribe.

If you wanted to subscribe users from the backend, you would need to use [Instance ID APIs](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances) from your backend service.

Example:

```
// to list the subscriptions for a given token:
GET https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/nKctODamlM4:CKrh_PC8kIb7O...clJONHoA?details=true
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

// to subscribe
POST https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/nKctODamlM4:CKrh_PC8kIb7O...clJONHoA/rel/topics/movies
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
```

Like you said you need this token. To get this token on the web for a user, use [firebase messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client).

Comment: Your answer is not relevant anything in the question. He just ask how to create a registration for a web user, not how to subcriber to a topic- this thing is so clear!

Comment: Maybe I did not explain well. The two questions I see are:

The issue I am having is figuring out "how to create Topics". My understanding is that I need to pass in a Token in order to create topics, but I can't find "where to create Tokens for a web user" in their SDK.

And in theory I wanted to answer those: There is no such thing as creating a topic, subscribing is creating and I showed an example of how to subscribe. And for the second one, I pointed to the firebase messaging APIs. And thankfully the link is still valid. 
But please feel free to add a better answer.